# htaccess redirect domain wih all its rankings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

i wanted some information please about how can i redirect my domin to new domin and transfer all rankings and all page positions on google to new domain ?

the first part i know is to verify my new domain on google webmaster tools

then it says about "301 redirect", ok i do to domain registrar and set 301 redirection from domain.com to newdomain.com but i been wondering how can i do for my other pages ? for example on my old domain i have domain.com/page1.php how can i redirect that to new domain ? if i only redirect domain.com to newdomain.com from my domain registrar and when i go to newdomain.com/page1.php will i get my old page ? or i have to set 301 redirect or each of my pages ? if yes then how do i do it using php or htaccess of any other better ways ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this htaccess code on your old domain. It will redirect all the old page of the old domain to newdomain.

for example: 
olddomain.com/page1.php will be redirected to newdomain.com/page1.php automatically.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: dear how do i redirect my old page not domain. your answer is not explaining anything

Comment: i have updated my answer . hope this will help you now

Comment: really only one line code works for all that? i don't need to add line for each page ?

Comment: Yes it will work if your server have url rewrite option enabled. Just put this code on the top of the htaccess file.Don't forget to replace newdomain.com with new domain.

Comment: Hello bro again. i need a little help on my robot.txt file. i am trying to tell google to Not index any files that is in this folder but i don't know if i am doing right or not check here's my robots.txt file http://imgh.us/robotstxt.png